# What is wrong with my method?

Tags: java

I just wanted to create a method which can convert a number from binary system(base2) to decimal system(base10). But I come up with some problems. I don't know how to correct it. Here is my method

```
public static int toDecimal (String base2) 
   {
     int sum=0;

     for ( int k=base2.length(); int i=0; k>0, i<=base2.length()-1; k--, i++)
     {
       char symbol = base2.charAt(k);
       sum= sum+ symbol*i;
     }
     return sum;
   }
```

P.S: I could not be able to convert a character to integer type **(sum+ symbol*i;)**. 
If possible, could you also give some advice about it.

Comment: I sorry for typing the whole code awkwardly:

Comment: public static int toDecimal (String base2) 
   {
     int sum=0;
     
     for ( int k=base2.length(); int i=0; k>0, i<=base2.length()-1; k--, i++)
     {
       char symbol = base2.charAt(k);
       sum= sum+ symbol*i;
     }
     return sum;
   }
   
}

Comment: Might need to use a ParseInt() since you are passing in a string

Comment: No error is shown first in the for statement

Comment: Hint: `String.charAt(0)`, when the string in question is "1101", will not return 1. It will return 49, or `0x31`... the Unicode codepoint of `1`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What output do you get? What do you expect? Please take a look at the [How do I ask a good question page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as on the [On-Topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I expect to convert a number given in binary system to decimal system. I do not get any output at this moment.

Comment: @S.Dovra If you need the decimal value of a binary number you can use Integer.toString(number,10); directly but if you want to write your own code then it is a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is not working because of incorrect for loop syntax - you can use ; symbol only two times inside the parentheses. Also `sum = sum + symbol * i;` is not right coversion formula.

It seems that this code resolves your problem

```
public static int toDecimal(String base2) {
    int sum=0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = base2.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(base2.charAt(k))) << i;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I hope that this helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But honestly speaking I didn't understand "<< i;"

Comment: << means left binary shift, i - bits count to shift. Each shift by one bit = multiply by 2

Comment: Thanks you. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

just **some minor changes** to your for loop will get the code working

```
public static int toDecimal(String base2) {
    int sum = 0;    
    for (int k = base2.length() - 1, i = 0; k>=0; k--, i++) {
        int symbol = (int)base2.charAt(k)-48;//0 is 48; 1 is 49 in ASCII
        sum = (int) (sum + (int) symbol * Math.pow(2, i));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

here you go

Comment: Thank you very much. But I didn't understand this line "int symbol = (int)base2.charAt(k)-48;//0 is 48; 1 is 49 in ASCII"

Comment: Sorry it may come to you ridiculous but as I am a beginner in learning java, I am having hard time with understanding even kind of simple codes.

Comment: no problem, @S.Dovra you see in ASCII the char '0' is = 48 '1' is 49 and so on. that's why there is -48 to get '0' as numeric 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

In you for loop you initialize 2 variables. Between them you have a ; (semicolon) but there should be a , (comma).

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the need for the parseInt call, and to start from the beginning of the string, you can use

```
   public static int toDecimal( String str) {
      int val = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         val = (val<<1) + ((str.charAt( i ) == '0') ? 0 : 1);
      }
      return val;
   }
```